# Como faço para chamar uma função no swift xcode

Tags: classes, swift, xcode, static, extension

Boa noite, tenho uma função que esta atrelada a um botão, gostaria de chama-la diretamente sem a necessidade do botão, o que faço?

A função...

```
static func goToTutorialOrTo(market: Market, from viewController: UIViewController) {

    BusinessesContainer.selectedMarket = market

    AnswersHelper.sendAccessMarketTracker()

    if UserDefaultManager.didSawTutorial() {
        let rootMarketViewController = StoryBoard.rootMarketViewController()
        viewController.present(rootMarketViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let tutorialViewController = StoryBoard.main().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tutorial")
        viewController.present(tutorialViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

A função chamada pelo botão...

```
extension SupermercadosZonaViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        StoryBoard.goToTutorialOrTo(market: selectedMarketsToShowInTableView[indexPath.row], from: self)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return StoryBoard.isIpad ? 175 : 110
    }
}
```

Minha tentativa de chama-la diretamente

Primeira...

```
StoryBoard.goToTutorialOrTo(market: Market.init(json: <#T##JSON#>)!, from: self as! UIViewController)
```

Segunda...

```
SupermercadosZonaViewController()
```

Em nenhuma das duas tive sucesso.

Comment: Qual é o erro que você encontra ao chamar a sua função? Por favor, compartilhe o log também.

Comment: quando uso segunda opção    teste>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but the object was already deallocated2018-05-16 16:02:51.915443-0300 Mercadapp[5068:62259] Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but the object was already deallocated

Comment: O erro diz que você usou um objeto que não "administrava" a sua própria memória (`unowned reference`), digo, não tinha uma relação forte (`strong`) com o objeto em questão. Parece que não tem nada a ver com a forma que você está apresentando sua tela, mas sim com algum objeto usado nessa rotina. Dica: procure acerca desse bloco de código no seu projeto por uma _capture list_ ou alguma referência à `Unmanaged`.

Answer (score 1):

A função que você quer chamar é a `goToTutorialOrTo` certo? Pelo código que você compartilhou, esta é uma função estática, ou seja, pertence à classe onde foi definida.

Para chamá-la, você pode fazer assim:

`Classe.goToTutorialOrTo(market: nil, from: nil)`

Onde `Classe` é o nome da classe onde esta função está definida. Não esqueça também de passar os parâmetros `market` e `from`.

Comment: Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'Market'

Comment: Sim, lembre-se de passar os valores corretos para os parâmetros `market` e `from`. O `nil` que usei aqui foi só um exemplo.